# Prevent Google Feed API from using cached feed

Tags: rss, google-api, google-feed-api

I am using the [Google Feed JSAPI](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide) to read/parse a feed. The problem is, when the feed changes, the previous entries become invalid (links and images don't work) so I *cannot* load a cached version of the feed. I thought there would be an option when loading the feed to not use the cached version but I don't see one. My solution is to do add in a variable (t) to the end of the feed url so it is "unique" but this seems hacky (but it works). Anyone know of a better way to do it?

```
    function onLoad() {
      // Create a feed instance that will grab feed feed.
      var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(feedLocation+"&t="+new Date().getTime());

      // Request the results in XML (so that we can parse out all the info
      feed.setResultFormat(google.feeds.Feed.XML_FORMAT);

      //must set this - if you don't, it defaults to 4
      feed.setNumEntries(50);

      // Calling load sends the request off.  It requires a callback function.
      feed.load(feedLoaded);
    }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? The problem here is that the server providing the feed is using caching based on the feed's URL. So if I add a random string to that URL's query string, then this will not only bypass Google's caching but also that of the server. Guess I have to modify the server to add a special *bypass external cache* parameter which gets ignored when doing internal caching.

Comment: Nope, no solution other than what I mentioned in my question - adding in the time as a "random" parameter. It works, just not as clean as I'd like.

Comment: I'm doing the same now, too, adding something like: `'?bypass_cache=' + Math.floor(Date.now() / refreshIntervalInMs)`

Comment: Ah - that's not a bad solution - at least it does cache it but it does so in a way that is controlled by refershIntervalInMs. Still a hack, but more elegant than mine which NEVER uses the cache.

Answer (score 2):

This answer might be coming in late, but I came across this post and got the solution using `pxpgraphics` comment. For those who need to invalidate the cache, this will do it. Note that this code example is pulling other data from the RSS feed; modify for your needs.

```
google.load("feeds", "1");

function initialize() {
    var feedLocation = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml";

    /*  Use the randomNum and the time to invalidate the Google cache and 
        fetch the latest articles.
    */
    var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
    var url = feedLocation + "?&t=" + new Date().getTime() + randomNum;

    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(url);
    feed.setNumEntries(1000);
    feed.load(function(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
      var container = document.getElementById("feed");
      for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));
        div.innerHTML += "<br>" + entry.publishedDate;
        div.innerHTML += "<br>" + entry.content;
        container.appendChild(div);
      }
    }
  });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

This code assumes you have this `DIV` on the page:

```
<div id="feed"></div>
```

Comment: That works, but it's no better than what I was doing with "new Date().getTime()". I was hoping for something more elegant that didn't require tacking on a "random" parameter and actually did use the cache. So far, the solution @feklee proposed using refreshIntervalInMs is closest to what I wanted.

Comment: You're right. I wish there was a built-in way to tell Google to not cache it. Maybe they prefer this way, as it probably requires less work for their servers.

Answer (score 0):

try `feed.includeHistoricalEntries();` It might solve your issue.

Comment: (BTW, keep the Vogon poetry going!)

Comment: From the API docs, that doesn't sound like it will do what I need. In fact, it sounds like I want dontIncludeHistoricalEntries(). I'll give it a try though and see. RE: Vogon Poetry - I will! :) http://myvogonpoetry.com is my blog :)

Comment: Oh ok, sorry. So, you want to "invalidate" the cache. Maybe asking for the URL with a random parameter?

Comment: That's exactly what I said I was doing now: "My solution is to do add in a variable to the end of the feed url so it is "unique" but this seems hacky (but it works)" but I was looking for something that was less of a hack :)

Comment: This random parameter can also be a random number..

`var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);`
`var url = feedLocation+"&t="+new Date().getTime() + randomNum;`

Comment: Thanks, @pxpgraphics. The random number solution worked for me.