# Google Ajax feed cache

Tags: ajax, caching, pinterest, google-feed-api

I am getting a Pinterest board feed via an Ajax call. However changes on the wall are not visible in the result. I have searched for a solution to get around the caching. But I seem to have a problem implementing it.

```
//url to the feed
var url = 'http://pinterest.com/' + this.options.username + '/feed.rss?nocache=' + (new Date).getTime();

///Google service
var api = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=" + encodeURIComponent(this.url) + "&num=" + this.options.limit + "&output=json_xml&callback=?";
```

This trows an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'feed' of null

{"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "Feed could not be loaded.", "responseStatus": 400}
```

When I leave out the '?nocache='+(new Date).getTime(). The cached feed is loaded.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30223534/177416